# Android Parcelable casting error

Tags: java, android, parcelable

So I'm about to crazy with this issue.

The main point is as following:
I have an `Object` that implements `Parcelable`. This object is passed around between `Activities` easily and without issues.
But if I attempt to read it from a `Bundle` in `onRestoreInstanceState`, after storing it with `onSaveInstanceState`, I get an exception about casting to invalid class. Below is the code for storing and reading, plus the `Exception` thrown.

`onSaveInstanceState`

```
Log.d(TAG, "Address is null:" + (userAddress == null));
if( userAddress != null )
{
    Log.d(TAG, "Address class:" + userAddress.getClass());
}

saveInto.putParcelable("UserAddress", userAddress); <-- Storing here
```

`onRestoreInstanceState`

```
Log.d(TAG, "Contains: " + retrieveFrom.keySet().contains("UserAddress"));

userAddress = retrieveFrom.getParcelable("UserAddress"); <-- Reading here

Log.e(TAG, "Loaded-Address was null:" + (userAddress == null));
```

`Exception`

```
W/Bundle﹕ Key UserAddress expected Parcelable but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
W/Bundle﹕ Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable
    at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:810)
    ...
```

The log shows that right before storing, the object is not null and the correct class. But after retrieving, it's null.
I have found a Android Bug that mentions something like this, but not exactly:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38303

The Object does not contain anything other than Primitive data like Strings and Longs.
Any ideas or suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: there has to be somewhere where you call `putString("UserAddress", "something");`

Comment: You should probably include the code for your object showing your Parcelable implementation

Comment: Is `userAddress` a string, or your Object?

Comment: JESUS TAKE ME NOW!!
@njzk2: I was calling ```putString("UserAddress", some string);``` somewhere in the ```Activities``` super-class ```onSaveInstanceState```.
A round of beers on me!! (If you post the answer @njzk2, I can accept the answer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Key `UserAddress` expected `Parcelable` but value was a `java.lang.String`.

That indicates that the Bundle contains a `String`

The reason is that somewhere you call

```
saveInto.putString("UserAddress", "something");
```

and that overrides the other value that you try to save into the Bundle.

I would recommend using more specific keys, and declaring them in a separated config file, so you can see in one glance who uses them.