# Intent Mediastore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE refuse putExtra arguments

Tags: java, android-intent, mediastore

```java
final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyDir" + File.separator);
root.mkdirs();
final String fname = "img_"+ System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";
final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
Uri mImageUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
final Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 30);
takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri.toString());
if(takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
  activityResultLauncher.launch(takeVideoIntent); 
}
```

The logs says that:

```
W/Bundle: Key output expected Parcelable but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable
        at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1008)
        at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:8524)
        at android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData(Intent.java:11656)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1741)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5404)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:584)
        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:234)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$2.onLaunch(ComponentActivity.java:218)
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$2.launch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:162)
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher.launch(ActivityResultLauncher.java:47)
        at com2.data.bbstar.PostActivity$3.onClick(PostActivity.java:479)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7441)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7418)
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:835)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28675)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7829)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:982)
```

When I click to record, the activity close directly.
When I don't putExtra, the activity works but I can't use the video (logs says that the video doesn't exist).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Parcelable casting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31727511/android-parcelable-casting-error)

Comment: I don't understand what I have to do because I can't change the name of the key ?

Comment: I think you should convert the string into object